# Is there a way to update existing file with Json data in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

We have a complex class containing Collection. Every object of this class should be written into file. Is there an efficient way to update the data of the files, instead of rewriting the whole content of the file.
Example:

```java
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add("foo");
        arr.add("bar");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(arr));
        arr.add("baz");
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(arr));
```

Output:

```
["foo","bar"]
["foo","bar","baz"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java File Replace Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133391/java-file-replace-lines)

Comment: @pringi as far as I'm concerned json objects are written without new line symbol, so I'm not sure if this works in my case.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70480667. What do you mean by "instead of rewriting the whole content of the file"? As pointed out in a comment on that other question the OS does not support inserting characters in the middle of a file.